# Slick insert, type mismatch

Tags: scala, types, slick

I'm trying to insert some data into my database using Slick. I've successfully been able to query the database, but can't quite understand how to insert data using the documentation examples.

I've gotten to the point where all that's supposedly wrong is that my `action` isn't of the correct type and it throws the error

```
type mismatch;
 found   : slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Unit,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write with slick.dbio.Effect.Schema]
 required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[com.ojolabs.customer.avro.CustomerEvent,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]
      db.run(action)
```

I'm not quite certain how to return the types that are specified as required, using the code I've already written.

I'm calling my schema from here:

```
trait CustomerEventsComponent {
  def customEventsManager: CustomerEvents.Async
}

trait DefaultCustomerEvents extends CustomerEventsComponent{
  self: DatabaseComponent with ExecutionContextComponent =>

  lazy val customEventsManager = new Async {
    override def create(phoneNumber: String, createdAt: DateTime): Future[CustomerEvent] = {

      val action = Schema.CustomerEvents.userAction

      //this is the line that throws the error
      db.run(action)

    }
  }

}
```

And am creating the action in here

```
object Schema {
  class CustomerEvents(tag: Tag) extends Table[CustomerEvent](tag, "customer_events") {
    def id: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def customerId: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("customer_id")
    def eventType: Rep[String] = column[String]("type")
    def createdAt: Rep[DateTime] = column[DateTime]("created_at")
    def version: Rep[Double] = column[Double]("version")
    def data: Rep[JsValue] = column[JsValue]("data")
    def metadata: Rep[JsValue] = column[JsValue]("metadata")

    def * = (id, customerId, eventType, createdAt, version, data, metadata) <> (CustomerEvent.tupled, CustomerEvent.unapply)

  }

  object CustomerEvents {
    val all = TableQuery[CustomerEvents]

      val userAction = DBIO.seq(
        all.schema.create,
        all += CustomerEvent(
          UUID.randomUUID(),
          UUID.randomUUID(),
          "hello",
          DateTime.now(),
          1.0,
          Json.toJson("{\"hello\" : \"its me\"}"),
          Json.toJson("{\"hello\" : \"its me\"}"))
    )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To keep this answer a little shorter, I'm going to refer to `DBIO[T]`, which is an alias in Slick for a `DBIOAction[T, NoStream, Effect.All]`*

## Why you see the compilation error

The error is saying the compiler expects a `DBIO[CustomerEvent]` but found a `DBIO[Unit]`.  It expects that type because `create` is defined to return a `Future[CustomerEvent]` (so `db.run` should return that).

However, `Schema.CustomerEvents.userAction` calls `DBIO.seq`. `seq` is a way to combine actions and ignore the results. The return type of `DBIO.seq` is a `DBIO[Unit]` (reference: [Scala Doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIOAction$)).

So that's why you see the error: the code is combining actions using a method that throws away the result.

## What to do about this

There are a few things you could do about this.

1. If you really don't want the result of the insert, change the type of `create` to be `Future[Unit]`
2. If you do want a non-`Unit` result, you'll need to switch to a different "combinator" than `seq`.  I'd suggest `andThen` in this case, which combines two actions, keeping the value of the second one.  I'll explain that in a moment...

### The result from an insert

`+=` defaults to returning the number of rows affected. That would be a `Future[Int]` type on `create` if that's what you want.

The `userAction` would end up as: `all.schema.create andThen (all += ...etc)`

Or you could use a for comprehension if you prefer:

```
for {
  _            <- all.schema.create
  rowsAffected <- all += ...etc
} yield rowsAffected
```

(which isn't using `andThen` but ends up with the same result).

However, if you want the case class as a result... well, you create the case class, so you could `yield` it in that for comprehension example above. Slick also supports `returning` and `into` as a way of changing the return type of an `+=` expresson: it's described in [the reference manual](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/queries.html#inserting).